# Why does the mappedBy parameter cause infinite recursion in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

These are two entities, each with more fields but these two are causing StackOverflow. When I'm using only **@JsonMannagedReference** and **@JsonBackReference** and not using **mappedBy**, infinite recursion doesn't exist. Still, in that case, I'm unable to create bidirectional relation, when I add a **mappedBy** parameter it causes a StackOverflow error.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Business {

@OneToMany(targetEntity = ProductCategory.class
            , cascade = CascadeType.ALL
            , fetch = FetchType.LAZY
            , mappedBy = "business"
    )
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<ProductCategory> productCategories;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class ProductCategory {

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Business.class
            , cascade = CascadeType.ALL
            , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "business_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Business business;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a very similar setup and it works. I see two differences.

First, we do not set **targetEntity**, JPA should be able to figure that out based on field types.

Second, we excluded "business" fields from toString and equalsAndHashCode generated for ProductCategory class.

Try adding annotations

```
@ToString(exclude = {"business"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"business"})
```

to your **ProductCategory** class.

That should exclude cyclic calls in toString and equals/hashcode methods and take away your unwanted infinite recursion.

Comment: Imo it's even better to use `@ToString.Exclude` and `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` instead of `@ToString(exclude = ">field-name<")`